# What is the fiber of the tangent bundle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle

A fiber bundle is a space $(E,B,\pi,F)$ such that $\pi:E\rightarrow B$ and $E$ locally looks like the product space $B\times F$.

If M is a smooth manifold, the tangent bundle on M is the space $(T(M),M,\pi,F)$, which is also a fiber bundle. What is the fiber $F$ of the tangent bundle? the fiber at $p$ is denoted $T_p(M)$, but is there a "universal fiber?" If not, why is there a universal fiber for other fiber bundles?

Comment: A smooth manifold has no canonical basepoint, so its tangent bundle has no canonical fibre. This is the same as for any topological fibre bundle in the category of unpointed topological spaces. If you work with pointed spaces or manifolds then bundles do have a canonical fibre.

Answer (score 1):

The fiber would be the model space of the manifold, namely $\mathbb{R}^n$ if the manifold is defined to be locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, whose elements can be identified with tangent vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The fiber of a fiber bundle is defined to be the space $F$. By definition. So the fiber of the tangent bundle of an n-dimensional manifold is $\mathbb R^n$.